# Why aren't my column borders full height?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Using Bootstrap 5.3. I wanted all the contents in the three columns to be vertical aligned, so I added `align-items-center` in `.row`. But the borders don't seem to be stretched to the top and bottom (see yellow circles). I could use `.card` component, but wondering if it could be done without `.card` component.

[image]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row align-items-center border-top border-bottom border-dark-subtle fs-5 text-center text-secondary">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-4 p-5">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x50" class="mb-3" width="200">
    <p>Looking to replicate the media object component from Bootstrap 4? Recreate it in no time with a few flex</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-4 p-5 border-start border-end border-dark-subtle">
    <span class="d-block display-3 text-light fw-bold">5G</span>
    <p>This is some content from a media component. </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-4 p-5">
    <span class="d-block">Up to</span>
    <span class="d-block text-success display-3 fw-bold">95%</span>
    <p>Network coverage</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try the .h-100 class to ensure that each column takes up 100% height of the parent container.

Comment: As you have use align-items-center class on row and it aligning at center. Remove that class to achieve what you want. Hope that work for you :)